# Python: if not or statement vs nested if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

I'm having a very hard time wrapping my head around if not or statements. Thanks to stackoverflow, I'm aware the the expression proceeding the or statement will only execute if the first if not statement is False, but all my fingers seem to want to type when confronted with a possible use case of this, is rather a nested if statement.

For example, the following classes are producing the same output for whatever x is.

```
def if_not_or(self, x):
    if not isinstance(x, int) or x % 2 == 0:
        return False
    return True

def nested_if(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        if x % 2 == 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Even though the first method clearly appears to be more elegant, does it offer any particular advantage over the ladder method? I fear that if a potential use case for this appears within one of my projects, I'll simply opt for the nested if approach because it's easier for me to wrap my beginner-intermediate programming mind around. Thanks very much for any enlightenment on the topic.

Comment: Readability matters.  If performance is not a problem, I'd prefer readability over stylistic choices.

Comment: In general, think `unless`... or `when`... if you only need one of the logical alternatives to proceed. `If`... is good for binaries, something like `choose`... or `depending on` ... when a list of options makes more sense.

Comment: @dardisco unless or when makes much more sense in my head. I was looking for a way to comprehend this logic and that just did it. This community is amazing.

Comment: @Idlehands. With performance in mind, which of the three solutions listed in this thread would be the most efficient? I'm hoping the answer will answer my own question on what impacts performance.

Comment: I can't test right now but my gut feeling is the difference between the three are negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third approach to your problem, that is:

```
def direct_return(self, x):
    # return True if x is an odd number, False otherwise
    return isinstance(x, int) and x % 2 == 1
```

With any of these approaches you will see a performance difference. But as suggested in comments, readability counts.

Comment: This third approach seems to be the most elegant and readable. Thank you!